# End and Home buttons don't work inside docker container

Tags: docker

I was asked to raise this on SO by the Devops community: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/13626/end-and-home-buttons-dont-work-inside-docker-container

When I'm in my windows terminal I can use the `Home` and `End` buttons on my keyboard to move the cursor to the beginning or end of what I'm typing. I use this often. However, if I enter a docker container this doesn't seem to work. To reproduce, I run this:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

Then I type `abc` followed by the `Home` and `End` button on my keyboard. The `Home` button does nothing, and the `End` button prints a tilde (`~`) to the screen instead of moving my cursor.

How do I get these buttons to work as expected?

Comment: I was asked to raise this here instead of on DevOps: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/13626/end-and-home-buttons-dont-work-inside-docker-container

Comment: Have you tried the same on other containers or Is it just with this image of ubuntu?

Comment: @i4nk1t same behaviour with `debian:latest` but it works as expected with `centos:latest`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing TERM to the value $TERM had before the container was launched, for example:

```
export TERM=rxvt-unicode
```

Replace rxvt-unicode with whatever your $TERM variable had in it just before you launched the container.